# FFMpeg not printing SDP information to console

Tags: ffmpeg, rtp, sdp

I was trying to create an FFMpeg stream and read it from VLC player, but I am getting an error saying SDP is required. However FFMpeg is not printing the SDP information to console as it is supposed to. How can I get the SDP file for the stream?

Here is the command I am using to stream

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -r 10000/1001 -i video="screen-capture-recorder" -vcodec libx264 -tune zerolatency -b 900k -f mpegts rtp://127.0.0.1:1234
```

Comment: may be able to use rtsp instead...FWIW `ffmpeg -i \vids\sintel.mpg -an -f rtp rtp://127.0.0.1:2000` worked here to output SDP information...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what I had done wrong. I was previously using this command:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -r 10000/1001 -i video="screen-capture-recorder" -vcodec libx264 -tune zerolatency -b 900k -f mpegts rtp://127.0.0.1:1234
```

Which I changed to this:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -r 10000/1001 -i video="screen-capture-recorder" -vcodec libx264 -tune zerolatency -b 900k -f rtp rtp://127.0.0.1:1234
```

I just changed "mpegts" to "rtp" since that is the protocol I was using.